# Why select option shows the values only after i click on it?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

So basically after i load/reload the page the select options not showing on the first click and the values not showing until the second click for some reason
ill be glad for some answers 
im still new with coding so be gentle with me :)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Company } from '../_models/company';
import { CompanyService } from '../_services/company.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-company',
  templateUrl: './companies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./companies.component.css']
})
export class CompaniesComponent implements OnInit  {
  selectedCompany: Company;
  companies: Company[];
  
  
  

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }




  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCompanies();
    

  }

  loadCompanies() {
    this.companyService.getCompanies().subscribe((companies: Company[]) => {
      this.companies = companies;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  // selectedChangeHandler(event: any) {
  //   this.selectedCompany = event.target.value;
  // }

}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 mt-5 bd-sidebar">
  <label for="">Select Company</label> <br>

  <select id="select" data-target="#navbarDropdown" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany"  >
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <!-- <option *ngFor="let value of companies" value="{{value.name}}">{{value.name}}</option> -->
    <option  *ngFor="let value of companies" [ngValue]="value">{{value.name}}</option>
      </select>
</div>



<!-- <select class="form-control col-lg-8" #selectedValue name="selectedValue" id="selectedValue" [(ngModel)]="company" (ngModelChange)="assignCorporationToManage($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let value of companies" [ngValue]="company">{{value.name}}</option>
</select> -->

<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item">Company name: {{selectedCompany.name}}</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Company address: {{selectedCompany.address}}</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Company estimated revenue: {{selectedCompany.estimatedRevenue}} </li>
</ul>
```

[image: Thats the problem]

Comment: Look in the console. You must have some error because at the beginning you are looping over an uninitialized array.

Comment: core.js:5871 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at CompaniesComponent_Template (companies.component.html:25)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:11926)
    at refreshView (core.js:11773)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13213)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11504)
    at refreshView (core.js:11825)
    at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13138)
    at refreshView (core.js:11796)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13213)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11504)

Comment: how do i make it load the array and only then load the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `companies` array is declared but not initialized before the `loadCompanies()` is called. So it would be better to wrap the template in a `*ngIf` directive to make sure the array is initialized before it is used.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="companies">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 mt-5 bd-sidebar">
    <label for="">Select Company</label> <br>
    <select id="select" data-target="#navbarDropdown" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompany"  >
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option  *ngFor="let value of companies" [ngValue]="value">{{value.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="selectedCompany">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Company name: {{selectedCompany.name}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Company address: {{selectedCompany.address}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Company estimated revenue: {{selectedCompany.estimatedRevenue}} </li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thanks for answering ive tried to put *ngIf like you wrote but its still not working

Comment: Try replacing `[ngValue]="value"` with `[ngValue]="value.name"`.

Comment: it wont work because im retrieving the whole array not just instance of it and yes ive checked